# pip install biopython stuck in import 'keyring.backends.macOS'

Tags: python, pip, biopython

I have been trying to install biopython after ssh'ing and have been repeatedly encountering the same problem. The command I am running is `python -v -m pip install biopython` to see exactly what is going wrong, and the process gets stuck with the last message on screen being`import 'keyring.backends.macOS' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fedb14195e0`. I have been checking for help and seen that it should have asked for the password, but this has not happened to me. The installation process just stops and hangs there indefinitely.

Any clue on what may be going wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: can you show the full error message traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue while installing geopy on a Raspberry 3b. I aborted the install and exported the following variable:

```
export PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring
```

Afterwards, the installation worked. Can't explain why tho..